# XML string array deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I Have a XML string

```
<ItemAttributes>
      <Binding>Misc.</Binding>
      <Brand>Gilbert</Brand>
      <Department>mens</Department>
      <Feature>Elasticated waist with drawcord</Feature>
      <Feature>Two pockets with reinforced stitching at base</Feature>
      <Feature>Reinforced seams for strength in wear</Feature>
      <Feature>Off set inside leg seam to reduce chaffing</Feature>
      <Feature>100% Cotton Twill</Feature>
</ItemAttributes>
```

and class

```
[Serializable()]
public class ItemAttributes
{
    public string Binding { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Feature")]
    public string[] Feature { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize xml to object, "Feature" has no value at all. I want it to be an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemAttributes
{
    public string Binding { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Feature")]
    public string[] Feature { get; set; }
}
```